# Excel unstacking data into multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365

I am struggling with unstacking, there are many easy Power Query and Pivot solutions , however i would like to have the solution in formula's so people understand the power of formulas.
Marketing, PR, Presenteren, Reclame and Schrijven
[Dataset to be unstacked contains 5 values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqWFT.png)

As you can see the labels are combined labelnames.
[Output required after unstacking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC6YN.png)

I hope someone can help me with the formulas to use to get this result.

Comment: the power of formulas is great when used on the right problem, here you will find the power of power query far more efficient and easy to achieve, teach and replicate. than trying to achieve with formulas alone.

Comment: You sample picture is not very clearly, What is KTH_PR??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the headers:

```
="KTH_"&TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE($B$2:$B$14))
```

This to get the values for a particular column (placed in the first unstacked row):

```
=FILTER($A$2:$A$14,$B$2:$B$14=MID(D$1,5,LEN(D$1)))
```

You would then copy that formula to each column:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out. I have added the statements to my sheet, with the full amount of data, but i noticed that after a while the wrong numbers hit the outcome, so hence somewhere something doesn't go as expected. Would it be possible to upload my file in this system or does it only accepts screenshots? Othewrwise pb your email and i will mail you my file so you can have a look. The filtered data should be the unstacked column data and that is not the case unfoirtunately. Thanks as your statements did work in your dataset which i recreated,